# Gap-free object sequence as a parameter using Oracle PL/SQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence

Good day, everyone!

I've got a bunch of sequences. For example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_id
    INCREMENT BY 1
    START WITH 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 20000
    NOCYCLE
    CACHE 1999;
```

But since I'm constantly using Merge, I've had the issue of gaps in the sequence that I needed to solve. This function works great for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fseq_id RETURN INTEGER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN seq_id.NEXTVAL;
END fseq_id;
```

So my question is if I could use a parameter or a variable to use the same function for multiple sequences. Maybe with dynamic sql? It's further complicated by having to use these sequences over different schemas (as the tables for merge are located in different schemas), so I've got to give them grants and public synonyms.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by ensuring you have gap-free sequences? Why are gaps in sequences such a problem?

Comment: In my experience in practice it is almost impossible to implement sequences that are always gap free. Additionally you also typically reduce the performance and concurrency by trying to reduce gaps. I don’t really understand what your function is doing but in your example sequence you could for example reduce the cache to 1 to reduce the possibility to have gaps but this will also have a negative effect on concurrency.

Comment: Fyi. https://youtu.be/B5JltFoe5Ho

Comment: Watch the youtube video in comment by Pugzly. Answers all questions about gap free sequences.

Comment: You can't ensure sequences to be gap-free, unless you can your transactions never rollback. 

If you want something to be gap-free, you need to code it yourself. This will not give good performance.